# Weird resampling when I try to export an Image

Tags: image-processing

*Mathematica* language newbie here. I wrote the following code to quantize an image:

```
basepath = "~"
SetDirectory[basepath]
jpgpath = FileNameJoin[{basepath, "jpg"}]
pngpath = FileNameJoin[{basepath, "png"}]

domquant[path_, n_] := 
 Image[{List @@@ 
    DominantColors[Image[ColorQuantize[Import[path], n]], n]}]

(*Convert each jpg in path to its 256-color quantized sample*)
Scan[( \
 img = domquant[#, 24];
    Print[#, " ", img];
Export[
    FileNameJoin[{pngpath, StringJoin[FileBaseName[#], ".jpg"]}],
    img,
    "JPEG", ImageResolution -> 300, 
ImageSize -> {8192, 512}]) &, {FileNames[
"*.jpg", {jpgpath}][[1]]}]
```

If I change the 24 in the `domquant` call to a higher value I get what looks like a rasterized image (I think).  Specifically, a gradient is applied.  For example, here's the result of `domquant[#, 256]`:

[image: wtf]

However, if I leave the value as `n = 24` or some other smaller number, I get a nice image like this which has discrete boundaries between each value of `n`, and is actually what I am trying to achieve:

[image]

So, why is 24 the magic number beyond which the blur effect takes place?  How can I get an image with nice discrete colors using a higher value of `n`?

In response to Szabolcs, if I remove the `ImageResolution` and `ImageSize` options, I get this image:

[image]

Not what I'm looking for.  I want to create an image like the second one above, where each of 256 colors is represented discretely, and is of arbitrary size.

In response to Simon Woods, if I add `Resampling -> "Nearest"` to `Export`, I ge this image with `n=256`, again blurry:

[image]

**Thanks to everyone who commented, the following comment from SimonWoods helped me understand**.  Here's the final (working) code and the resulting (quite beautiful) image.

```
basepath = "~"
SetDirectory[basepath]
jpgpath = FileNameJoin[{basepath, "jpg"}]
pngpath = FileNameJoin[{basepath, "png"}]

domquant[path_, n_] := 
 Image[{List @@@ 
    DominantColors[Image[ColorQuantize[Import[path], n]], n]}]

(*Convert each jpg in path to its 256-color quantized sample*)
Scan[(
   img = domquant[#, 256];
   img = ImageResize[img, {8152, 512}, Resampling -> "Nearest"];
   Print[#, " ", img];
   Export[
    FileNameJoin[{pngpath, StringJoin[FileBaseName[#], ".png"]}],
        img, "PNG"]) &, {FileNames["*.jpg", {jpgpath}][[1]]}]
```

[image]

Comment: The settings `ImageResolution -> 300, 
ImageSize -> {8192, 512}` trigger resampling.  Don't use these settings.  If you do need to resample the image, do it explicitly using `ImageResize`, then export the resized image at 1-to-1 pixel size.  Also, don't export such a quantized image to JPEG.  The lossy compression will introduce colours that you did not originally put in the image.  Use PNG instead.

Comment: @Szabolcs answer?

Comment: @Yves I was waiting for the OP to react

Comment: @Szabolcs I removed those options, see above.  Still not exactly what I'm looking for.

Comment: @Szabolcs, in v8 at least, the `Automatic` setting for the `Resampling` option in `ImageResize` uses nearest neighbour only if both image dimensions are <=24, and one of the interpolating methods for images larger than that. So the OP will need to specify `Resampling->"Nearest"` to get the desired result.

Comment: @SimonWoods I'm using v9.  Adding `Resampling -> "Nearest"` to `Export` options has no noticeable effect -- the image is still blurry.

Comment: @g33kz0r, it's an option for `ImageResize`, not for `Export`. The idea is you remove the options from `Export` and use `img = ImageResize[img, {8152,512}, Resampling -> "Nearest"]` to change the image size.

Comment: Can you post the image you get when you remove `ImageResolution -> 300, ImageSize -> {8192, 512}` and update your code in the question?

Comment: Szabolcs, see my question, I already did that.  @SimonWoods your suggestion did the trick.  Please add your comment as an answer and I will accept it.

Comment: Szabolcs, I see that you mentioned `ImageResize`, which was ultimately the correct suggestion, but since I'm a M'ica newb, your comment wasn't explicit enough for me to understand precisely what I needed to do. @SimonWoods your comment and follow-up was clear, and doing what you said did the trick.  So you win.

Comment: ... Also, because I was using the wrong terminology (rasterization instead of resampling), here's a really snappy explanation of the concept of resampling as applied to images:  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resampling_(bitmap)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To prevent interpolation between adjacent pixels requires the option `Resampling -> "Nearest"` in `ImageResize`. This is the default setting for images smaller than $24\times24$ pixels, but larger images will use one of the other resampling methods (I'm not sure which). The desired result can therefore be obtained with:

```
img = ImageResize[img, {8152,512}, Resampling -> "Nearest"]
```